# How to access an object within another object in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm currently trying to access objects within other objects using Meteor.
The Object looks like:

```
({
title: "Bubble Explosion",
createdAt: new Date(),
label: {
        status: "live",
        class: "success"
        } 
})
```

My problem is that I dont know how to access the status and class of the label object. All other attributes just work fine..

```
<tbody>
   {{#each imports}}
      {{> tableRow}}
   {{/each}}
</tbody>

<template name="tableRow">
...

  <td>
     <span class="label label-{{label}} text-xs-left">{{label.status}}
     </span>                 
  </td>
...
</template>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a helper for your template to retrieve data, like that:
[{Doc here}](https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html)

**mytemplate.html**

```
<template name="table">
    <tbody>
      {{#each getImports}}
           {{> tableRow}}
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</template>

<template name="tableRow">
  <td>
     <span class="label label-{{label.class}} text-xs-left">{{label.status}}
     </span>                 
  </td>
  <td>
     {{title}}                
  </td>
</template>
```

**mytemplate.js**

```
Template.table.helpers({
  getImports() {
    return [
      {
        title: "Bubble Explosion",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        label: {
              status: "live",
              class: "success"
        } 
      },
      {
        title: "Bubble Explosion #2",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        label: {
              status: "live",
              class: "success"
        } 
      },
    ]
  }
})
```

To work with MongoDB data you can update you **mytemplate.js** file

```
Template.table.onCreated(function() {
  let instance = this;
  /* Subscribe to data */
  instance.subscribe('imports')      
})
Template.table.helpers({
  getImports() {
     return Imports.find({}).fetch()
  }
})
```

Comment: Im already retrieving this object using a helper function from my mongo db:

Template.overview.helpers({
 imports: function() {
  return imports.find({});
 }
 })

Comment: try by addind the fetch() function: `return imports.find({}).fetch()`

Comment: Also, do a `console.log(imports.find({}).fetch())` before the return to check you have the data on your client. And if you don't check if the publication is good ?

Comment: console.log output looks like this:

Object
_id
:
MongoID.ObjectID
createdAt
:
Sat Jul 09 2016 19:25:18 GMT+0200 (CEST)
label
:
Object
class
:
"success"
status
:
"live"

Comment: So my code should work fine. You need 2 templates, one for the subscription and the helper. And the other to display each row